# How to select periods of time with empty data?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to find out all periods with empty data, given the following table `my_table`:

```
id         day       
29         2017-06-05
26         2017-06-05
30         2017-06-06
30         2017-06-06
21         2017-06-06
21         2017-07-01
29         2017-07-01
30         2017-07-20
```

The answer would be:

```
Empty_start    Empty_end
2017-06-07     2017-06-30
2017-07-02     2017-07-19
```

It's important that the number of months is considered. For example, in the first row the answer 2017-06-**31** would be incorrect.

How can I write this query in Hive?

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd period end with 2017-07-19?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Yes, updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select date_add(day, 1) as empty_start, date_add(next_day, -1) as empty_end
from (select day,
             lead(day) over (order by day) as next_day
      from t
      group by day
     ) t
where next_day <> date_add(day, 1);
```

Comment: I get the error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token (' on running this query: `select date_add(to_date(day), 1) as empty_start, date_add(next_day, -1) as empty_end from (select to_date(day), lead(to_date(day)) over (order by to_date(day)) as next_day from my_table group by to_date(day)) my_table where next_day <> date_add(to_date(day),1);`

Comment: @Dinosaurius - the query is fine.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I get this error: `SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:269 Invalid table alias or column reference 'day': (possible column names are: _c0, next_day)`. Just to notice that `day` is string. I double check that there is a column `day` inside the table `my_table`. Therefore I am a bit confused and do not understand the error.