# Find periods with empty data

Tags: sql, hive

I have this table `my_table` in Hive:

```
id         day       
29         2017-06-05
26         2017-06-05
30         2017-06-06
30         2017-06-06
21         2017-06-06
21         2017-07-01
29         2017-07-01
30         2017-07-20
```

I want to get periods of empty data:

```
Empty_start    Empty_end
2017-06-07     2017-06-30
2017-07-02     2017-07-19
```

I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978201/how-to-select-periods-of-time-with-empty-data):

`select date_add(to_date(day), 1) as empty_start, date_add(next_day, -1) as empty_end from (select to_date(day), lead(to_date(day)) over (order by to_date(day)) as next_day from my_table group by to_date(day)) my_table where next_day <> date_add(to_date(day),1);`

I use `to_date` because `day` is string.

Finally I get the following error message:

`SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:269 Invalid table alias or column reference 'day': (possible column names are: _c0, next_day)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to include the right columns in the subquery.  Here is what I mean:

```
select date_add(dd, 1) as empty_start, date_add(next_day, -1) as empty_end
from (select to_date(day) as dd, lead(to_date(day)) over (order by to_date(day)) as next_day
      from my_table
      group by to_date(day)
     ) t
where next_day <> date_add(dd, 1);
```

Comment: Now it works! Thanks. So, do I understand correctly that this query finds ALL periods of time with empty data? These periods might be 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, etc. Right?

Comment: @Dinosaurius . . . Except for anything at the beginning and the end.  I should emphasize, though, that this is basically your original intention, just with the syntax fixed.